# iOS Statusbar text color when there is no Actionbar

Tags: nativescript

I want to color my Statusbar text white. This is no problem when i have an Actionbar, but when i set the actionbar to hidden, the color is black again.

This is the code i used:

```
<page actionBarHidden="true" backgroundSpanUnderStatusBar="true"></page>
```

And this is the javascript code:

```
var navigationBar = frameModule.topmost().ios.controller.navigationBar;
navigationBar.barStyle = 1;
```

---

**Question:** How to color the statusbar when there is no actionbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find solution of this behavior in this GitHub issue:[here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2264)

Comment: Adding the 2 keys to the plist solved my problem (UIStatusBarStyle, UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance)